# images Not Loading in xhtml2pdf with medial_url, Any Solutions? django

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf, pisa

I'm encountering a peculiar issue in my Django project involving xhtml2pdf. When I attempt to generate a PDF using xhtml2pdf, the images, which load correctly when viewing the Django page, fail to display in the generated PDF.
in my setting:

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My models

```py
class Reserva(models.model):
    ImagenCarnet = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='App/carnets/example.jpg')`
```

My views.py

```py
def DescargarReserva(request, id):
    reservas = Reserva.objects.filter(idSolicitud=id)
    Orden=Reserva()
    data={'reservas':reservas, 'Orden':Orden}
    pdf_response=genpdf('templatesApp/pdf.html', data)
    if pdf_response:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf_response, content_type='application/pdf')
        #agrecar variable con id como nombre de archivo quizas se usa {}
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reserva.pdf"'
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Error al generar el PDF", status=500)
```

In my template

```html
<img src="{{reserva.ImagenCarnet.url}}" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 200px;" />
```

I've tried using `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ reserva.ImagenCarnet.url }}`, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. The images load correctly when accessing the Django page, but in the PDF generated by xhtml2pdf, they are not displayed.
Here are the images illustrating the problem: 
[With Django, loads correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzTbt.jpg)
[With  xhtml2pdf, does not load correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzO0X.jpg) 
[File source (for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfYWi.jpg)

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this discrepancy between image loading in Django and xhtml2pdf. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share the definition for `genpdf`

Comment: `from django.template.loader import get_template
from io import BytesIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.http import HttpResponse


def genpdf(template_src,context_dict={}):
    template=get_template(template_src)
    html=template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='App/pdf')
    return None`